# convert timestamp to date in custom commands

Tags: python, django

i am creating custom commands in django. i have a problem with conversion timestamp to date by methods like fromtimestamp. i have such error:
*line 13, in handle
timest_conv = datetime.fromtimestamp(timest)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument*

this is my class with handle

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args , **options):
        r = requests.get('https://api.metals.live/v1/spot/silver').json()
        price = r[0]['price']
        timest = r[0]['timestamp']
        timest_conv = datetime.fromtimestamp(timest)
        print(price,timest, timest_conv )

        return
```

Comment: What does the `r[0]['timestamp']` looks like?

Comment: the last one 1634309968403

Comment: when i convert it to int(r[0]['timestamp']) error is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp is expressed in *milliseconds* since January 1st, 1970. You thus should divide these by 1'000 to retrieve the timestamp:

```
timest_conv = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timest)/1000)
```

for the given sample timestamp, we get:

```
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1634309968403/1000)
datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 15, 16, 59, 28, 403000)
```